# Why is my second monitor not working?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, multiple-monitors

Since I have my new computer, I have a very weird problem.

Facts:

**New Computer**:

- Motherboard: ASRock Z77 Pro 3
- Graphics-card: Asus1GB D5 X EN GTX560 DCII OC/2DI R
- CPU: Intel i5-3570
- Windows 7 64-bit (newly installed)
- 500W beQuiet special edition (92% efficiency)
- 8GB 1333MHz DDR3 Corsair RAM (CL9)
- Scythe Mugen 2
- 2 magnetic HDDs + 1 SSD
- 1 DVD-R

**Old Computer**:

- mobo: Asus P55 something
- GPU: Asus1GB D5 X EN GTX560 DCII OC/2DI R
- CPU: Intel i7-870
- OS: Windows 7 64-bit
- PSU: 550W Corsair
- RAM: 8GB 1333MHz DDR3 Corsair (CL9)
- Scythe Mugen 3
- 2 magnetic HDDs + 1 SSD
- 1 DVD-R

On the old computer it worked fine with two monitors.
Moving to the new (I took the same Graphics-card) it only works with one. The weird thing I mentioned above: no matter which one, but if I put both there only one is available.
There is no reaction at the start (where normally - at least if I remember correctly - the monitor shortly went from "standby" to "on").

Windows does not recognize a second monitor in the Device Manager.

I have the latest drivers for the motherboard and graphics card. I have the latest BIOS drivers.

I am out of ideas.

---

Edit: completed computer setup

Comment: Does Windows shows a ? icon in device manager for the monitor?

Comment: Nothing. only the one.

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: Windows 7 64bit

Comment: Did you plug both monitors into the graphics card, or one into the motherboard and one into the graphics card? You may be using processor graphics...

Comment: Both via card via DVI-D

Comment: Please come back with exact specifications of both systems.

Comment: What do you think could have an influence there? Rest is new an taken from a purposed system from a manufacturer.

Comment: ...proposed system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this very simple.

- For one, you have only replaced your Motherboard and Processor, and that is the only difference between your old and new computer. Nothing else has changed. Nevermind the SMPS, it doesn't matter!
- Second, it looks like your using the same hard drives in the same order. It also seems your booting from the same old installed same Operating System on those hard drives, without doing a clean install.
- If you search Google properly, most people have reported Graphic Card issues and driver issues, When they have replaced their Motherboard and the Processor with a different one.
- The only solution to this is, do a clean install, or get a temporary hard drive and clean install the OS and drivers on it and check if it works. A clean install will definitely solve you problem.

Here are some links to support what i have said. Please read these threads:

- [Upgrading the Motherboard on Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/3856-upgrading-motherboard-windows-7-a.html)
- [Upgrading the Motherboard and CPU on windows 7](http://www.overclock.net/t/685936/upgrading-motherboard-and-cpu-in-windows-7)

Comment: Sorry, but I did a clean and full install of Windows 7 and all drivers. Why shouldn't that graphics-card work with a new Motherboard and CPU? Of course I see this must be the reason if it still works with the old computer. But that still is no reason! A clean install I have and it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Ah, u did not mention it in your question. Then you need to trying re-installing once more on a clean and formatted hard drive .. and try using the windows default WDDM drivers for your graphics card using Windows Update. If your dual monitors work well, you can later try over riding it with your vendor drivers. Atleast you will be able to catch the issue.

Comment: added the information :). Although I don't really believe that original nvidia drivers will render my graphics-card useless, I might try that.

Comment: just to corner down the problem.. u can definitely use your nvidia drivers later..

Comment: uninstalled nvidia drivers. Installed Windows version of NVidia drivers from Windows Update. Worked. Incredible :). Now i'm trying to reinstall latest nvidia drivers. Thanks!

Comment: Still working. Any explanation for that?

Comment: your drivers were malfunctioning ... sometimes installations malfunction .. so dont worry about it .. its solved .. enjoy ur new PC ..